Jetpack compose Row height: Why is too high?
I have a Row that contains three Boxes. Each Box has a Text. I want each Box to have the same height equal to the tallest Text. In my code each Box has the same height, but the Row is too high with space above and below the Text:
    Row (
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.dimen_2dp)),
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
            .padding(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.dimen_2dp))
            .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(end = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.dimen_2dp))
                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.tertiaryContainer)
                .fillMaxWidth(0.2f)
                .fillMaxHeight()
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "aaa / bbb / ccc",
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(start = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.dimen_2dp))
                    .align(Alignment.Center),
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge,
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.tertiary
            )
        }
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(end = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.dimen_2dp))
                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.tertiaryContainer)
                .fillMaxWidth(0.5f)
                .fillMaxHeight()
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "aaa",
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(start = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.dimen_2dp))
                    .align(Alignment.Center),
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge,
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.tertiary
            )
        }
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.tertiaryContainer)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .fillMaxHeight()
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "bbb",
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(start = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.dimen_2dp))
                    .align(Alignment.Center),
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge,
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.tertiary
            )
        }
    }



I resolved the issue by using weight rather than fillMaxWidth.
Box {
        Row(
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(2.dp),
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
                .padding(2.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(2.dp)
                    .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.tertiaryContainer)
                    .weight(.5f)
                    .fillMaxHeight()
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "aaa / bbb / ccc",
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(start = 2.dp)
                        .align(Alignment.Center),
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge,
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.tertiary
                )
            }
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(end = 2.dp)
                    .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.tertiaryContainer)
                    .weight(1f)
                    .fillMaxHeight()
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "aaa",
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(start = 2.dp)
                        .align(Alignment.Center),
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge,
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.tertiary
                )
            }
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.tertiaryContainer)
                    .weight(1f)
                    .fillMaxHeight()
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "bbb",
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(start = 2.dp)
                        .align(Alignment.Center),
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge,
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.tertiary
                )
            }
        }
    }


